# Android StudioのExtended ControlのLocationタブの地図が表示されない

Tags: android-studio, windows-10

当方Windows10のPCでAndroid Studioのバージョン「Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch1」を使用しております。
去年まで使えていたのですが、今年に入ってからVirtual Device ManagerのExtended ControlのLocationタブに存在している地図が添付画像のように白背景となり表示されなくなってしまいました。
本現象について何か心当たりのある方、ご教授お願いできないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

再インストールや最新バージョンインストールして確かめてみたのですがダメでした。
また画像上の検索ボックスに何か入力しても、以前は候補となる地名が羅列されていたのですが、今は何も表示されない状態です
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio を現時点での最新版である 2023.1.1 への更新を試してください。

類似の質問が英語版や Google の IssueTracker でも報告されていますが、Android Studio の更新で直ったケースがあるようです。

[Google Maps UI missing in extended controls - Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71316605/2322778)
[Can't see google maps inside Android Emulator Extended Controls](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228201899?pli=1)